# Build with docker into host directory

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm fairly new to docker, but I'm trying to see if I can use it to build the frontend app for a project using it and take the built app and hand it off to another tool.

So ideally, I'd like to:

1) Setup environment using Dockerfile.
2) Run `npm run build`

What i'm not sure is how can I access the build folder from the container from my host?

My docker file is:

`FROM kkarczmarczyk/node-yarn:latest
WORKDIR /app
ADD . /app
RUN yarn --ignore-engines
RUN yarn run build`

Then I do:

`docker build -t build-app`

From the prompts it looks like it builds properly, but I don't know how to get the built app from the container. Its building to a `/dist` folder on the container.

How can I access it from the host?

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount a volume to your host machine, which allows you to share that particular directory, bidirectional with the container.

You could do this something like

```
docker run -v <host-path>:<container-path> <image-id>
```

Refer this answer. [docker mounting volumes on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311613/docker-mounting-volumes-on-host)

Comment: The problem is that I run the npm build script from the dockerfile which means that when I run docker build, it will build my app. I can see in the console when I. Hold the docket image that it also runs the npm script, so I never actually run a docker container like you mention