# How to enable code running in a docker container access files on the host on which the container is running?

Tags: docker, docker-container

I have an application running as a docker container on a host. What I want is to have a location in the host filesystem accessible from the application. 
The reason I want a location outside the docker container is that the said location will contain a text file that would be updated by a piece of code running on some other host.

What location could be used for this purpose ?

Comment: The answer to this question might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311613/docker-mounting-volumes-on-host

What it boils down to is that docker's "volumes" functionality is what you want to look into

Answer (score 0):

You need to add a volume during the run command using `-v`.

```
docker run -d -v <path-of-volume-in-host> <path-to-mount-in-container> ubuntu
```

You may refer [this](https://docs.docker.com/engine/tutorials/dockervolumes/) for more information.