# Docker with Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, docker

I create an Dockerfile with Postgresql with this code:

```
FROM postgres:9.4
MAINTAINER Fabio Ebner
ENV POSTGRES_PASSWORD="dna44100"
ENV POSTGRES_PORT=5432
EXPOSE ${POSTGRES_PORT}
COPY init.sql /docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
```

so How can I specify to always save my db data in my user Machine? cause with this code everty time I stop the container my data are lost

Answer (score 0):

You will need to mount a volume. pointing your host machine to the container's directory /var/lib/postgresql

Source: [docker mounting volumes on host](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25311613/docker-mounting-volumes-on-host)

Answer (score 0):

You need to mount a volume to the `data` directory of PostgreSQL.

You can use the following, using the [`docker-compose` file](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/):

```
version: "3"

services:
  test-postgresql:
    image: postgres:9.4
    container_name: test-postgresql
    ports:
      - "5432:5432"
    environment:
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: dna44100
    volumes:
      - ./init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
      - ./folder-on-host:/var/lib/postgresql/data
```

With the docker-compose file you can start the container with `docker-compose up` and stop the container with `docker-compose down`. The database and settings are saved on the specified directory (`./folder-on-host`).

If you want to remove the volume you can use the command: `docker-compose down -v`

---

You can also use the `docker run` to mount a volume, using the [`-v` or `-volume` option](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#mount-volume--v---read-only):

```
docker run -v ./folder-on-host:/var/lib/postgresql/data yourimagename
```

Comment: And in a single how can I do? Dockefile  I create a VOLUME ["/Users/user/Projetos/docker/data"] . so when I run docker run myContainer he will create this dir? how I link this dir with a postgres dir inside my container?